# Access S3 from Lucee/Railo/Coldfusion built in functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion, railo, lucee

I am having trouble accessing an S3 bucket to just list the files using Lucee. I have followed the directions [here](http://www.oxalto.co.uk/2012/12/14/railo-and-amazon-s3/) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-4439fdac128193edfd6-7f08.html) with no luck. I keep getting the error message that the **directory does not exist**.

This is in my Application.cfc:

```
this.name="s3-test";

this.mappings = {
    "/s3test" = "s3://luceetest/blah"
}

this.s3 = {
    "accessKeyid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "awsSecretKey": "ZZZZZ/XXXXXX/YYYYY",
     "defaultLocation": "Oregon",
 };
```

This is the code I am testing with:

```
<cfsetting showDebugOutput="Yes">
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="s3://coldlucee/blah" name="blah" recurse="yes" type="file">
<cffile action="write" output="s3 specs" file="s3://coldlucee/blah/test.txt"/>
```

I have also tried to map it inside of the web interface using the format `s3://accessKeyID:awsSecretKey@coldlucee/blah` as the resource but it always shows up as red which means it can't be found.

I am hoping someone can help me out with this, it seems so simple in the articles I have read so I might have a configuration error on the Amazon side. I have tried to make the bucket public to no avail though.

Comment: What is the AWS policy you have in place for S3 resources with respect to the accessKeyid you nominated?

Comment: I have all the options checked for my username under permissions

Comment: Try naming the region to "US West" instead of "Oregon"

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to get CF's implementation of S3 to work either.  I ended up using an S3 REST Wrapper I found here:

https://gist.github.com/CFJSGeek/3f6f14ba86049af75361

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually got it working like it should be. The crazy thing is I didn't change anything. I am wondering if new S3 accounts take some time to propagate settings or something because it mysteriously worked after 24 hours.